# Notification Action Button in 2022

Tags: java, android, notifications

Does anyone know how to create a notification with action button which links Broadcast receiver NOW, when you cant just do this:

`.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, " ", pendingIntent)` //deprecated

but you need put there just "Action" ??